# Stop TextChanged event from firing Leave event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a simple WinForms application for a public school where users can identify themselves by entering either their network IDs (which are **not** protected information) or their system IDs (which **are** protected information). I want to switch to a password character when the program detects a system ID (which is working just fine); however, when I do this, my application also fires the textbox's Leave event, which tells users to fix a problem with the login data...before there's even a problem.

Here's my code:

```
void login_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    login.UseSystemPasswordChar = login.Text.StartsWith(<prefix-goes-here>);
}

private void login_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (login.Text.StartsWith(<prefix-goes-here>) && login.Text.Length != 9)
    {
        signInError.SetError(login, "Your System ID must be nine digits.");
        login.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
    }
    else if (login.Text.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        signInError.SetError(login, "Please enter your username or System ID.");
        login.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
    }
    else
    {
        signInError.SetError(login, string.Empty);
        login.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I don't know that this will cause a ton of problems, and I **could** move this validation step to the Click event of the sign in button on my form, but I'd rather do validation piece-by-piece if possible.

Comment: It didn't make any sense to me either. I checked the call stack in Visual Studio, and it shows login_TextChanged as having called login_Leave. I've gone through the designer several times to make sure that there's nothing else tied to the event, cleaned, and rebuilt the application as well, but it still happens.

Comment: Okay, it appears that the critical detail -- which I left out, not knowing it was a critical detail -- is that this TextBox control is inside a GroupBox control. I moved the TextBox outside the GroupBox control, and these events fire as intended. Inside the GroupBox, it acts as I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the TextBox inside a GroupBox does reproduce that behavior-- which is odd.

If you want to keep your GroupBox, here is a work around:

```
private void login_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  login.Leave -= login_Leave;
  login.UseSystemPasswordChar = login.Text.StartsWith(<prefix-goes-here>);
  login.Leave += login_Leave;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the `Leave` event fires when the login `TextBox` is inside a `GroupBox` control. Replacing the `GroupBox` with a simple `Label` control prevented the code within the `TextChanged` event from firing the `Leave` event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a quirk of the UseSystemPasswordChar property.  It is a property that must be specified when the native edit control is created (ES_PASSWORD).  Changing it requires Winforms to destroy that native control and recreate it.  That has side-effects, one of them is that the focus can't stay on the textbox since the window disappears.  Windows fires the WM_KILLFOCUS notificaiton.

Being inside a GroupBox is indeed a necessary ingredient, Winforms doesn't suppress the Leave event when it gets the notification.  Bug.

Many possible fixes.  You could set a flag that the Leave event handler can check to know that it was caused by changing the property.

Comment: No, it is not.  The `ES_PASSWORD` style can be changed at any time by sending [`EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761653(v=vs.85).aspx), and does not require recreation of the control window.

Comment: That has beans to do with the way it was implemented in Winforms and its support for Win98. I don't know anybody that is so eager to show his ignorance repeatedly.

Comment: Perhaps WinForms does recreate the control window, but MSDN says it isn't *required*.  Your answer uses the words *requires* and *must*, which are inaccurate (at least according to the Win32 docs).  And other online references that still cover Win95 indicate that `EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR` was supported on those OSes also.